# React JS add local font

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css

I want to add a custom font which is in my local machine, I added the font in the `src/fonts/` the font file itself is named `DIN Next LT Arabic Regular.ttf`.

I found one of the answers suggested that I should put it that way and add this line to my `index.css` file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DIN Next LT Arabic Regular' !important;
  src: local('DIN Next LT Arabic Regular'), url('./fonts/DIN Next LT Arabic Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and then import the `index.css` to my `index.js` which was already done by the `create-react-app` command.

But it's not working, and I have no clue why.

PS: I have a `.env` file which contains this line `NODE_PATH=src/` to not use relative path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "Web Font Loader" to import font in your react-app, so you can install this tool use

`npm install webfontloader --save`

This is just an example:

1- In your public/index.html copy the link of the font

2- Then open src/index.js and add:

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

  WebFont.load({

    google: {
      families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']

     }});
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue might stem from support and / or compatibility issues (I.E: what works on browser `x` might not work on browser `y`).

***What if the browser you're using doesn't support that particular font format?***

While I would normally recommend that you use a (free) service like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com) to get your fonts, there are times when you need to host and load your own custom fonts so I think you would be better off using [FontSquirrel's Web-Font Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), it's a service that allows you to upload a `.ttf` file and create a webfont package (a `.zip` folder that contains all the different font formats).

It also supplies you with a CSS file that (properly) links all the different font formats, ensuring you have proper support, you can find out more about Font Squirrel at [their blog](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog).

**NOTE:** I'm not associated with and don't work for Google Fonts or Font Squirrel, just a satisfied user of both services.

Comment: can't use google fonts, the font i want to use isn't there and i tried font squirrel, after trying to upload the font i got this message `Linotype has requested that their font DIN Next LT Arabic Regular be blacklisted by the Generator. You will not be able to convert this font.`

Comment: It appears that; that particular font is copyrighted, and you'll need to use another font. Have you looked at other fonts? Maybe checked out another (alternative) host's font list? Here's [A list of alternatives to Google Fonts](https://alternativeto.net/software/google-web-fonts/).